# CMake как правильно добавить файлы в качестве ресурсов?

Tags: c++, linux, cmake, resources

Я пытаюсь сделать приложение с тестами (Google tests, но дело не в тестах) и для тестов **решил создать тестовые данные, которые хотел бы прикрепить в качестве ресурсов**. Компилирую проект с помощью CMake, сам проект на С++. **Как правильно прописать в CMake добавление файла ресурсов?** Сейчас я прописываю файл тем способом что представлен ниже и ниже же функция проверки чтения файла которую я использую, но вот беда, файл не хочет читаться. **Если что то неверно делаю, то прошу указать, ранее не добавлял файлы подобным способом, для меня это несколько ново.**

Структура директорий следующая:

```
project/
|
*-- CMakeLists.txt
|
*-- Expert Librariy/
|   |
|   *-- Tests/
|   |   \-- CMakeLists.txt
|   |
|   \-- CMakeLists.txt
|
\-- Resources/
    \-- Test_MA_Std.csv
```

`project/CMakeLists.txt`:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10.2)

file(GLOB RESOURCE_FILES "Resourses/*")

message(${RESOURCE_FILES})

add_subdirectory(Expert\ Library)
```

`project/Expert Librariy/CMakeLists.txt`:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10.2)

add_subdirectory(Expert)
add_subdirectory(Tests)
```

`project/Expert Librariy/Tests/CMakeLists.txt`:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10.2)

project(Expert_tests)

include_directories(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../Expert/include)
include_directories(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG} -Wall -g")

file(GLOB CPPS "src/*.cpp"
    CPPH "include/*h")

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${CPPS} ${CPPH} ${RESOURCE_FILES})

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} 
    lib::gtest
    lib::Bonds_knifes
)

set_target_properties(${PROJECT_NAME} PROPERTIES RESOURCE ${RESOURCE_FILES})
```

Структуру директорий описал не полностью а лишь ту где лежат интересующие меня файлы. Файлы CMake через которые компилирую проект - приложил полностью что бы не было не каких недоговорок. Функция которая пытается прочесть файл и ее вызов - следующие:

```
struct file_closer {
    constexpr file_closer() noexcept = default;

    void operator()(std::ifstream* __ptr) const {
        if(__ptr->is_open())
            __ptr->close();

        delete __ptr;
    }
};

void read_file(std::string file_name) {
    std::unique_ptr<std::ifstream,file_closer> file(new std::ifstream(file_name));

    if (file->is_open()) {
        std::cout << "File was opened\n";
    }
    else {
        std::cout << "CAN`T OPEN FILE\n";
    }
}

int main() {
    read_file("Test_Ma_Std.csv");
    return 0;
}
```

Прошу напишите где я сделал ошибку или же свои соображения. 
Если я указываю полностью путь к файлу - то чтение происходит, так что дело точно не в С++ коде, как я понимаю файл просто не добавляется в качестве ресурса. Заранее благодарю.

Comment: `"Test_Ma_Std.csv"` - такой путь может быть использован для открытия файла, расположенного в текущей папке приложения. При чем тут ресурсы - непонятно.

Comment: @user7860670 экзешник может находиться где угодно. Я хочу сшить файл "Test_Ma_Std.csv" с экзешником, как файл ресурса и открыть его. Подскажите как это сделать если я что то неверно делал.

Comment: Ну во-первых ресурсы нельзя просто так открывать по имени файла. На Windows следует использовать `LoadResource` и т.д. Ну и прежде чем их добавлять, следует сделать ресурсный скрипт .rc На линиксе для тех же целей придется делать скрипт для линкера и придумывать собственное API для доступа. Лучше просто положите этот файл в папку с исполняемым файлом.

Comment: Как уже писал выше - не использовал ранее ресурсов. Подскажите как на чистом C++ это прописать ? Сейчас пока проект под Linux пишу, далее под Windows адаптировать собираюсь. Если сможете привести пример, либо ссылку на информацию - было бы замечательно.

Comment: На чистом С++ - никак.

Comment: @user7860670 Хорошо, а где почитать как под линукс виндовс это делается ?

Comment: Под линукс - сделай сам, под Windows - на msdn. Собственно тут уже заданно полно вопросов на эту тему...

Comment: Под линукс - сделай сам - да я то непротив) Но как я понял CMake - вроде поддерживает добавление ресурсов не так ли ? Если же я ошибаюсь, то подскажите если ли какие нибудь аналоги или же куда смотреть? Не буду же я велосипед заново изобретать, как минимум схожие технологии уверен есть. В сети видел что в QT есть ресурсы, но там фреймворк - понятно что это они дописали, однако возможно есть хоть пример какой либо. Я QT не использую, как пример написал просто

Comment: Cmake сам по себе ничего не поддерживает, обычно он только дергает соответствующие утилиты из тулчейна. В QT ресурсы есть, да. Ну а для линукса придется таки избретать велосипед. см https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1997172/is-there-a-linux-equivalent-of-windows-resource-files Заметьте, статья из linux joгrnal аж от 2008 года, а воз и ныне там.

Comment: @user7860670 благодарю за ссылку, изучу материал.

Comment: @user7860670, C# вполне себе поддерживает ресурсы на Linux.

Comment: @0andriy А при чем тут C#? Java тоже поддерживает ресурсы на Linux, но легче от этого не будет.

Comment: @user7860670 странно, но статья, что Вы скинули - открывается лишь в Tor, как я понял сам сайт уже прекратил свое существование. Способ интересный, попробую сегодня. Кто то (смотрю комментарий к вопросу что Вы скинули) себе кросс платформенный компилятор ресурсов написал, судя по описанию, в работе достаточно прост должен быть, тоже по изучаю. Видимо и впрямь каждый сам выкручивается как может.

Comment: linux joгrnal прекратил существование, это да. Но сайт вроде как продолжает работать и у меня открывается безо всяких проблем.

Comment: Ну положите себе содержимое в отдельную секцию бинарника, это с семидесятых поддерживается в Си/Си++ (как наследнике). Собирается с libelf, никаких велосипедов не надо.

Comment: А, почитал ссылку, там тоже самое рассказывают.

Answer (score 1):

Думаю вы все слишком усложняете: как я понял из вопроса - вам нужно чтобы экзешник открывал какой-то файл, но так как экзешник и файл могут быть в разных директориях, то это проблематично. Если файлы "ресурсов" не планируется перемещать после компиляции (а раз это тест - странно это было бы делать) то для решения этой задачи можно не прибегать к системе ресурсов а использовать функционал `cmake`. Тобишь в `cmake` берете абсолютный путь вашего тестового ресурсного файла (можно его даже пере этим скопировать в нужную директорию) и [конфигурируете](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.14/command/configure_file.html?highlight=configure#command:configure_file) `.hpp` файл где в соответствующую константу (или `define`) записываете нужное значение. В результате ваш экзешник, независимо от расположения, всегда будет обращаться к одному и тому же файлу, главное не перемещать (после компиляции) сам файл. Для теста - это вполне себе приличный вариант, хотя для конечной программы, конечно, не годится.

Comment: Вполне возможно что именно так и сделаю, однако для эксперемента попробую все же сшить файлы

Answer (score 1):

В CMake для тестов есть специальный модуль [`CTest`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.17/manual/ctest.1.html) и команда [`add_test`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.17/command/add_test.html). Они созданы специально для тестирования кода и предусматривают работу с файлами ресурсов.

Чтобы в вашем случае использовать этот модуль достаточно в файле `project/Expert Librariy/Tests/CMakeLists.txt` добавить этот код:

```
enable_testing()

add_test(NAME ${PROJECT_NAME} ${PROJECT_NAME} WORKING_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/../../Resources")
```

Этот код создаст новый тест с именем "Expert_tests", который запустит исполняемый файл сгенерированный таргетом "Expert_tests". При этом рабочая директория будет "Resources", так что файл "Test_Ma_Std.csv" будет доступен.

Чтобы запустить тесты нужно выполнить команду `ctest` внутри директории сгенерированной CMake. Либо же сбилдить таргет `RUN_TESTS`, который появится в проекте автоматически если используются тесты.

Comment: Благодарю за совет. Вариант безусловно хорош, возможно лучше того которым я решил воспользоваться, так как не требуется других библиотек для тестов. Однако я уже решил использовать гугл тесты, посему отложу этот способ для другого проекта. Не очень будет накручивать гугл тесты + CMake тесты.

Answer (score 0):

В общем, у меня было время и я сделал свой велосипед. Почти все сделано через генерацию кода с помощью CMake и основано на примере из статьи из LinuxJornal, которую мне скинули в комментариях. Всем спасибо, Ваши ответы помогли. Если вдруг захотите мое решение подправить, то буду благодарен за корректировки.

https://github.com/AndreyKrivcov/Resource-files-Extension

Comment: Ваше решение не будет работать если файл нужно модифицировать.

Comment: @Teivaz Так мне и не нужно его модифицировать. Мне нужен лишь встроенный файл ресурса.