# создание ресурса и работа с ним - cmake

Tags: c++, cmake, c++17

Не могу понять как создать ресурс cmake из 3 исполняемых файлов и запускать их из кода без обращения к каталогу, требуется запустить их из самой памяти, чтобы этих 3 файлов не было в каталоге

Структура проекта:

```
    - resource
        -- file1
        -- file2
        -- file3
    - main.cpp
    - main.h
    - CMakeLists.txt
```

CMakeLists.txt

```
add_executable(project main.cpp ${RESOURCES})

set(RESOURCES
    file1
    file2
    file3
)
```

main.cpp

```
    system("./resource/file1");
```

Как должен выглядить каталог после компиляций:

```
    - project
```

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1084884/cmake-как-правильно-добавить-файлы-в-качестве-ресурсов